# Why is this statement false? Can someone provide or direct me to a proof?

Tags: vectors

Question:
True or False: If $a = b$, then $||ai + bj|| =sqrt(2a)$

Answer:
False:$||ai + bj|| = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = sqrt(2)||a||$

Comment: What part of the answer you quote is not clear?

Comment: What if $a$ is negative?

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of the norm? If so, with simple algebra the answer should be quite clear

Comment: Thank you all! My apologies for asking seemingly silly questions, I work two jobs and am going back to school after a long time and, unfortunately, I have forgotten some of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose as stated that $a = b$. Try setting $a < 0$ as said by Jonathan in the comments. You should find that both sides of the equation don't hold. Secondly, it is possible to prove the alternative answer.

\begin{align*}
    \|ai + bj\| &= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\\
                &= \sqrt{a^2 + a^2}\\
                &= \sqrt{2a^2}\\
                &= \sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2}\\
                &= \sqrt{2}\|a\|
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the part that was unclear.